# Material Ui Drawer Broken on Build

Tags: reactjs, build, material-ui

I am using material ui with react and I had issue as soon as I wanted to deploy my site.
I think what issue is classnames are not been assigned on build for some reason I tried to drop the usage
of clsx pkg but still same issue, I don't know if there's other causes but I haven't found any one with same issue

Development version------------Build version

[image: Development version]
[image: Build version]

appBar + Drawer Component

```
export const NavBar = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const theme = useTheme()
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  // const [, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true)
  }

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AppBar
        position='fixed'
        className={clsx(classes.appBarTheme, classes.root, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open,
        })}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color='inherit'
            aria-label='open drawer'
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge='start'
            className={clsx(classes.menuButtonDrawer, {
              [classes.navHide]: open,
            })}>
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography
            style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }}
            component={Link}
            to='/'
            variant='h6'
            noWrap
            className={classes.root}>
            text
          </Typography>
          <DropDownAcc handleSnk={props.handleSnk} />
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant='permanent'
        className={clsx(classes.drawerTheme, {
          [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
        })}
        classes={{
          paper: clsx({
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
          }),
        }}>
        <div className={classes.toolbarTheme}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRight /> : <ChevronLeft />}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {[
            'My Profile',
            'New Room',
            'Browse Rooms',
            'Leaderboards',
            'Support',
          ].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <Box ml={0.5}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index === 0 ? <AccountCircle fontSize='large' /> : null}
                  {index === 1 ? <AddCircle fontSize='large' /> : null}
                  {index === 2 ? <Search fontSize='large' /> : null}
                  {index === 3 ? <Assignment fontSize='large' /> : null}
                  {index === 4 ? <Help fontSize='large' /> : null}
                </ListItemIcon>
              </Box>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  )
}
```

Theme Data

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  appBarTheme: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButtonDrawer: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  navHide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawerTheme: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9) + 1,
    },
  },
  toolbarTheme: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  contentTheme: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    marginLeft: 65,
    marginRight: 10,
  }})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and since I couldn't resolve it, here is a possible workarround.
Just change the variant of the Drawer component to "persistent":

```
<Drawer
        variant='permanent'
      ...
```

to

```
<Drawer
        variant='persistent'
      ...
```